# Using PHP to put subpage into a Variable instead of using $_GET

Tags: php, post, get

I am fully versed in how to get, and clean the vars in a `$_GET` and `$_POST`, and I understand that `$_REQUEST` listens for both GET and POST's.

I understand that the GET is `www.somesite.com?GET=MYVAR`, but my question is this. Can you take: www.somesite.com/MYVAR and put the subpage into a var, as apposed to using the          `?GET=MYVAR`

In PHP

Thanks,

Comment: you want to route the requests on your http server. what http server are you using?

Comment: The engine is called `mod_rewrite`. Google for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Apache, you would use the `mod_rewrite` module with an `.htaccess` file. There are tons of tutorials you can find via Google once you know the right words :)

Comment: Knowing the right works was Key! Thanks so much

Comment: No luck needed, now I know the keywords, its already been implemented at my site. Works a dream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this is actually less dependent on PHP and more dependent on your webserver. It's called rewriting URLs. If you're using Apache, it's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html) you'll need to look into.

Here's an example for nginx using a rewrite rule:

```
rewrite ^([^/]+)(/)?$ /index.php?var=$1;
```

Then you'll be able to access it using

```
$_GET['var'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

and then split it (e.g. explode | preg_split)?

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done using the `mod_rewrite` as mentioned in the other answers.  But you can also get the url from the `$_SERVER` variable and parse the resulting string.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php